# Having problems with Entity Framework with DbContext in Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, entity-framework, vps

I am currently developing a GT-MP server (Custom multiplayer mod for GTA V)
The server is running perfectly on my computer (windows) but when I try to run it on a Linux VPS I get some weird errors.

It has something to do with the Entity Framework because when I try to run a script that doesn't use it, it works perfectly fine.

I have been looking around the internet for hours for solution but nothing.
I thought maybe I need to install the EF on the Linux server? or maybe it doesn't have permission to access the database?
Any help is appreciated.

The error:
    https://pastebin.com/GGX7sAnq

```
https://puu.sh/wupk2/edcd948908.png
```

Comment: What version of .net are you using? And what version of EF?

Comment: Try to run with MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug and see what it shows. Also if you run debug build, try to test on release one.

Comment: EF version 6, and .net 4.5

Comment: @JoePhillips  
EF version 6, and .net 4.5

Comment: @Evk How do I run with that command? I am using Putty to run commands to the VPS

Comment: That's environment variable. You can set that as usual with "export MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug", then run your app. Version of framework is interesting too (you run on mono, so it cannot be .NET 4.5).

Comment: @Evk here's what I get https://pastebin.com/FHj8Pjdd Should I downgrade to .net 3.5? it says .net 4.5 in the build settings

Comment: I mean which mono version.

Comment: @Evk I have the latest version installed I think, I followed the install guide in the mono website

Comment: Looks like mono does support 4.5 though: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/

Comment: Hard to tell the reason from those logs unfortunately. I saw such errors, mono is not very stable. You can try to run release\debug versions of your application (as I suggested above) or downgrade mono to previous version (because current version has several bugs in it). And yes, mono is fine with applications complied for .NET 4.5.

Comment: @Evk Thank you, how can I downgrade my mono version? I'll try that

Comment: Depends on your OS, I think you didn't mention which OS you use. You can also just uninstall and install again (specific version). Just check your package manager about how to install specific package version.

Comment: @Evk Thank you so much, I downgraded to version 4.8 and now it runs perfectly fine! you're awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Evk for helping me, the answer was just to downgrade mono since there were some bugs with the latest version.

Edit:
Mono Vesrion I had problem with : 5.0.1 Stable (5.0.1.1)
Downgrading to version 4.8.1 seem to solve the problem!

Comment: Would be good to include which version exactly had a problem and to which you downgraded, for future visitors with similar problem.